# Consolidate/flatten nested lists in Android with RXJava2

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I'm struggling to come up with an RXJava2 Solution to "a simple problem". I am not extremely experienced with RXJava beyond the simple use cases.

Suppose I have a `Container` that looks like:

```
class Container {
   List<A> listOfA;
}
```

The rest of the model is a series of nested lists like this model:

```
class Base {
   // irrelevant content
}

class A extends Base {
   List<B> listOfB;
}

class B extends Base {
   // irrelevant content
}
```

Somewhere in my code, I obtain a `Single<Container>` like so:

(*note: the code/types/etc have been obfuscated/simplified for an easier reading*)

```
disposables = new CompositeDisposable(); // not important here

disposables.add(
    interactor.getTheContainer() // This returns a Single<Container>
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<Container>() {

            // on error ommited for clarity

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final Container value) {
               process(value);
            }
        })
    );

private void process(final Container container) {
    List<Base> items = new ArrayList<>();

    List<A> listOfA = container.getListOfA();

    for (A a : listOfA) {
        items.add(a);
        items.addAll(a.getListOfB());
    }

    // do something with "items" - ommited for clarity
}
```

I have been unsuccessfully trying to convert the method `process(Container)` to RXJava (maybe I shouldn't but now I want to know).

I can't even begin to list all the stuff I've experimented with, but I'm really new to RXJava 2 (most usages I've done in the past years with RX were simple Observables from Retrofit and nothing too fancy, or even as an Event Bus to replace Otto/Guava), so I am really not well versed in the arts of making good usage of the RX toolset. I *think* some sort of map should work, but the whole Java syntax gets confusing really fast for me when it comes to anonymous methods.

The question is:

Where should I read/look for ideas how to perform the same operation of the `process` method but with RXJava2?

Order **is** important, the final list looks like this with the current method and I need it this way:

```
0. A1
1. B1.1
2. B1.2
3. B1.nn…
4. A2
5. B2.1
6. B2.2
7. B2.nn…
8. A3
9. B3.1
…
```

You get the idea.

Any hints? I do **not** have Retrolambda or Java 8 (nor can use it, it's not my decision and I can't do anything about it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
List<Base> process(List<A> list) {
    List<Base> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (A a : list) {
        result.add(a);
        result.addAll(a.getListOfB());
    }
    return result;
}

interactor.getTheContainer() // This returns a Single<Container>
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .map(new Function<Container, List<Base>>() {
        @Override public List<Base> apply(Container c) {
             return process(c.getListOfA());
        }
    })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<Base>>() {
        @Override public void onSuccess(final List<Base> value) {
           /* display the list */
        }
    })
```

A more "convoluted" solution could replace the map above with some Iterable transformation via [IxJava](https://github.com/akarnokd/ixjava#ixjava):

```
.flatMapIterable(new Function<Container, Iterable<A>>() {
    @Override public Iterable<A> apply(Container c) {
        return c.getListOfA();
    }
})
.flatMapIterable(new Function<Iterable<A>, Iterable<Base>>() {
    @Override public Iterable<Base> apply(Iterable<A> a) {
        return Ix.<Base>just(a).concatWith(a.getListOfB());
    }
})
.toList()
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I knew I was close ;) I did not try the IxJava for adding an extra library requires a lot work ("asking, approving, management, etc. etc. etc. etc. etc. etc…")